# How To press One While Twilio Call is Making

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-python

I have this line of code in python to call in Twilio.

During a call, it says to press one to continue the call. So, how do I press one while on a call?

```
call = client_.calls.create(
                 record = True,
                 twiml=phone_call,
                 from_=from_phone_number_,
                  to = to_phone_number_,
                   url=url_to_xml)
```

Answer (score 1):

The keyword you are looking for is [DTMF tones](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-dtmf).
You can use the [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play#examples-2) verb to play DTMF tones as well as 1/2 second waits:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <Play digits="wwww3"></Play>
</Response>
```

You can use the [`<Pause>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/pause) verb to tell Twilio to pause processing TwiML for a specified number of seconds:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <Pause length="5"/>
    <Say>Hi there.</Say>
</Response>
```